# Gradle aapt error: syntax ")" not found on Android Studio 1.5.1 Linux

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, aapt

### Unburden

First of all, I would like to unburden: Android Studio **completely sucks** and it is by far **the worst** big IDE I've used all my life long! I got stuck on errors just for opening that thing! And when I have hardly fixed one, seventeen new ones come rightly from the hell to my screen! I am (trying) to use that piece of [you know] for 4 days now, and till now I was not able to code one single line of code! What does an IDE is supposed to be useful for again?

-- Edit1: I just installed the full 1.4.1 version right now and **first** thing it showed me was: `WizardException: Ignoring unknown package filter 'source-25'` and others errors.

-- Edit2: I did a new FRESH Mint 18 install in a completely clean partition, installed *only* Java 7 (Oracle) and tried to run the AS-1.5.1 but... the same error on install and a subtle different log of error messages (please, [see the log here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5cc8526f20b1c32e6d2cf0c15a418c30)) when `gradle`ing.

### The problem

Ok, the last problem (1.5.1) is that now I am trying to make gradle to build the "project" (it is just an empty activity created by the wizard, default code untouched) and I get this error:

```
~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication $ gradle clean build --stacktrace
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
//...[other succesfull msgs here]...
:app:mergeDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 16120822): /home/sidney/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /home/sidney/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 22545775): /home/sidney/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3: /home/sidney/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
//...[other repeated errors here]...
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/sidney/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 60 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
//...[other repeated errors here]...
```

**--- UPDATE: Please, see [this other log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77a55c717ba528b2dbe2d995a2e142df) of the external terminal used to run AS ---**

### What I've tried to solve that:

- Install `aapt` system-wide;
- Switch from Java 8 to Java 7;
- Change gradle to off-line;
- Change JDK configs to switch from the AS one to the system one;
- Set `SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT` to `30` (I changed back as you can see in the log link)
- Set `ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT` to `true`;
- Install via ubuntu-make and also via ppa;
- And so many others things I could find over Internet.

### Environment specs

- Linux Mint 18 (32 bits)
- AS 1.5.1 (now (trying to use) 2.1.0)
- Java Oracle 8 (Already tried the 7)

### Why don't I just switch to Eclipse with plug-in

I have a course in mind (in Udacity) and they use that "thing" and it is a prerequisite. I've sent 3 e-mails to them questioning about the possibility of use other IDEs but without answer after 4 days, unfortunately.

**Thank you so much for any help!**

Comment: It sounds like you have issues other than android studio. What's your `/etc/locale.conf`?

Comment: I don't have a `/etc/locale.conf`. Should I? Thanks and, I am sorry for my ignorance but what `locale` would have to do with those errors?

Comment: The fact that your error has a bunch of unprintable characters

Comment: Yeah, and when using IntelliJ PHPStorm 1 or 2 files are created in my $HOME named with another bunch of those characters (but PHPStorm works like a charm!)

Comment: @Falmarri following your suggetion I found some strange messages on external terminal used to start android studio. I updated the topic.

Comment: Your error isn't caused by Android Studio.. something messed up your environment and now it tries to execute `aapt` as a shell script, while it's actually a binary (which contain the word `ELF` in their header. That's obviously not a command that can be found). Maybe it's that odd terminal you use?

Comment: Thanks @zapl. The terminal I use is just the Gnome Terminal.

Comment: @Falmarri, I did 2 new updates to my question. Maybe we should discord about locale now. Any other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: While I may understand your frustration, this site focuses on solving specific problems.  As such, I edited out all unrelated stuff to make it easier focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: @AleksG Are you sure? Have you see **really** read I had said? Have you seen about the versions and the tries to make this *&%$# software to work? You just DELETED it? Are you kidding me???

Comment: I see you reverted my edit - it's your right. That said, yes, I was sure.  The part that I delete contained virtually no useful information - as for the versions, all it said is that you tried different versions of Android Studio - this is not helpful.  Instead you should state specifically what the current setup is.  Your complaining doesn't help.

Comment: No... you mean logs are not important and error messages are not important too... I will explain it: some dudes, friendly, pointed `locale` as the possible error source. My messages (and logs) point that it is not (probably) the problem. This is why I have posted logs, error messages and tries using other versions of this software.

Comment: This is for android studio to install on Linux, correct?
I will try to install on another ubuntu machine to see how it goes, at high level, I would do:
- install JAVA8 and export JAVA_HOME to that installation, log out and log in.  check it with java -version, and which java
- delete all ~/.AndroidStudio* 
- install Android Studio, looks like version does not matter to you, I would try 2.2.2 (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)
- start android studio and let download SDK and also NDK for you [I need check exactly prompt]

Comment: Thanks @Gerry I had not see your message before. Yeah, any version I will be able to install (if any) will be good! But the approach you said I had already tried (clear everything, environment vars, etc). I really appreciate your efforts to install in your Ubuntu (Mint here) to see what happens. It is worth remembering that my notebook is 32bits (core 2 duo, 4GB RAM, radeon, Mint 18). Thank you so much, dude!

Comment: I am aware that it is probably pointless writing this, but whatever problems you are having: Android Studio is one of the greatest IDEs that exist today, it is based on IntelliJ which - at least in my opinion - is the best IDE that exists. It would work flawlessly if you would be using OSX or Windows, it's just that Linux is, like it is many times, not without complications. Ranting about the IDE is not going to fix your problems, once your issues are solved I am convinced you will realize how great Android Studio actually is.

Comment: And also switching to Eclipse is not really an option since it is not supported anymore for Android development. Android Studio is now the official IDE and trying to use Eclipse and getting it to work with the new build tools and using all the new features would just cause more problems. Aside from the fact the Eclipse is just terrible...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that Eclipse is not supported for Android dev anymore. I did not know. But no, it is *not* terrible in any way. I had used it before to make some very basic apps when I was studying android and it were really fast and intuitive.

Comment: And @XaverKapeller, has AS a Linux version? What would you expect if you downloaded a Linux version to install in a Linux system? Would you say: oh! I should buy a Windows (urgh!) or a Mac! Probably not. You would expect it worked. Even if you had to fix some errors. But it is not the case. Have you some good idea to fix those? If not, let me to use my right of to *unburden* about something still is not good for the system I use (and love). It does not hurts anybody. And *thanks* for your downvote with no help.

Comment: I meant no offense and I didn't downvote your question. I was more trying to point out that Android Studio just has its problems on Linux - but otherwise is great.

Comment: Ok, no problem, and I am sorry. It was just a coincidence. Three minutes before you comment the question had been down voted. Other coincidence is that I was online checking the topic and updating sometimes. The most important to me is not the up/down votes but really fix this, because I can't see any sense in those problems. Hardness!

Comment: Yes, the major issue is that my familiar setting is 2.2.0+, that one needs 64 bit java and 64 bit operating systems: it conflicts with your 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution? Buy a 64 bits laptop! No installation error, no gradle error, no java error, no error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

That error looks like your build tools aren't properly installed/set up.  The aapt distributed with the build tools is versioned/linked with the tools, so studio probably isn't going to grab the random system level one.  Have you attempted to install them, or did the older Studio version fail to prompt you to do so?

Beyond that, I'm afraid that Studio 1.4 is *very* deprecated and was missing many, many fixes that are in the newer versions, so it's somewhat likely that you would run into random errors with that version :-(  What errors were you encountering with 2.2.1?  It would be easier for the Studio team to help address those versus anything you find in 1.4.

Comment: Hi @kathy. Thanks for your comment. Before installing each version, I empty all configs and SDK folders (.gradle included) and I mark *all* options to download (greater than 1GB in 2.2.1). So, I would expect `aapt` would be in the right version (that related to the build-tools being downloaded) since the own AS is downloading. Is this a wrong assumption of mine? How could I check the compatibility between `aapt`/build-tools versions? Thank you so much!

Comment: About your another question, in the 2.2.1 I fall in similar errors (at least they were just during the installation). One of them you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077163/gradle-project-refresh-failed-error-just-after-install-studio-2-2-1-no-coding. Other errors were happening in every build processes (probably gradle or aapt related). Now, after you comment, I started to think that I really have a build related problem in AS (gradle? aapt? something else? I dont know). Thanks.